# Entity Framework recursively include collection for each entity from included collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following where I am trying to include the addresses of the people in the cities of the countries.

```
Country country = _db.Countries
               .Include(p=>p.Cities.People.????)
               .Where(....)
```

Not sure how to work it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx):

> To include a collection, a collection, and a reference two levels down:
>
> ```
>     query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection.Select(l2 => l2.Level3Reference))).
> ```

So in your case try

```
Country country = _db.Countries
               .Include(c=>c.Cities.Select(
                   cc => cc.People.Select(
                   p => p.Addresses)))
               .Where(....)
```

Access to this extension method requires the directive
`using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: I'd also mention that the strongly-typed include requires adding: `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: For .net core the syntax is now .Include(c=>c.Cities).ThenInclude(cc => cc.People).ThenInclude(p => p.Addresses) see
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels

Comment: For those still on EF 6.x you can use the non-type checked string version of include `.Include("Cities.People.Addresses")` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading-multiple-levels

Answer (score 35):

You have to add an .Include call for each level in you object hierarchy tree:

```
 var result = db.Countries
            .Include(m => m.Cities)
            .Include(m => m.Cities.Select(v => v.People))
            .Where(....)
```

Edit : D.Stanley answer is better in terms of compact code, and works as well, I tend to prefer this syntax in terms of modularity.

Comment: If you are including level 3 childs you dont need to explicitly include level 2 childs  `.Include(m => m.Cities)` is not needed here.

Comment: Note that inverting the order can in some cases remove the need for the (in my opinion ugly) select statements: `db.People.Include (p => p.City).Include(p => p.City.Country)`. You can end it on a `Select(p => p.City.Country)` to receive a list of countries again.