# How to "group resolve" a property for a list of objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, select-n-plus-1

I have a list of some objects, which I populate from a database query result.

```
List<Competition> myList; // fetched from DB
```

If I need to access a property of one/several of the object in this list which requires to query the database again like this:

```
List<Person> compPersons = myList[0].Persons; // persons must be fetched in DB
```

then, is there a way to have but one db call which would fill `Persons` property for every `Competition` in `myList`?

```
List<Person> comp1Persons = myList[0].Persons; // Causes one big DB fetch
List<Person> comp2Persons = myList[1].Persons; // no more fetch required
List<Person> comp3Persons = myList[2].Persons; // no more fetch required
```

If I have 1000 competitions in my list I don't want 1000 queries when I iterate over the list and access Persons property.

EDIT: I wouldn't mind using a IEnumerable instead of List, if it allows more possibilities.

Comment: I suppose you use Entity Framework? Then you can use ".Include": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945115/entity-framework-include

Comment: Are you using any orm like L2Entities, L2SQL or dapper?

Comment: No, I don't use any of those.

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook: i don't like your approach, i would prefer lazy loading only the persons that are required not all. Why do you prefer loading all persons if someone uses the `Persons` property getter? That doesn't work anyway if  `myList` is a local variable since the property has no knowledge  of it.

Comment: This sounds even more complicated. When I access Persons property of one on the List<Competition> then it's likely (or even sure) I'll have to access this property for other items in the list.

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly then you can write a stored procedure that accepts comma separated values as parameter and fetch all the persons.

Comment: Why not fetch all data when program is loaded and store in a dictionary<Competition,List<Persons>> this way everything is loaded and accessible.

Comment: Because there are a lot of competitions. And that would totally forbid any DB change which would not get immediately reflected on the dictionary  (and vice-versa)

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook: why is it likely that you you need the persons from `Competition2-1000` if you access the persons of `Competition1`?

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook if you want active checking / check for people in competition every time it is clicked then you have 2 options the way you do it in your question above. Or you can use a dictionary as I said and have an event get raised whenever fb is changed to update the dictionary. Also you should change your question since you ask for a way to only query once. And you should use the @ then persons name so they get messaged that you have answered.

Comment: @TimSchmelter
Because I will iterate over all competition object and might access their persons property. If I access it once in a loop, there's a chance I access it again on some next iterations.

Comment: This is called the [SELECT n+1 antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)