# Return parent and children in single entity framework query WITHOUT returning IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

We have a rule to not expose `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` outside of the service layer so downstream code can't modify the query going to the database. This means that the types we return are like IList or ICollection.

I'm wondering how I might write a linq query to grab a parent and it's children in a single trip to the database without the child collections being defined as `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`.

For example, suppose the type being returned from the service is `ICollection<Parent>` where `Parent` is defined as this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If I define the query as this...

```
from p in dbContext.Parents
where p.Name.Contains("test")
select new Parent
{
    Children =from c in dbContext.Children
    where c.ParentId == p.ParentId
    select c;
}
```

It doesn't compile because `IQueryable` doesn't implement `ICollection`. If I add `.ToList()` to the parent and child collections, it compiles, but now it will do a separate trip to the database for each parent to get it's children.

As I'm writing this question it occurred to me that maybe the answer is to write the Linq query to select into anonymous types and then map it to the actual types to return. We use AutoMapper which could assist in the mapping. Any reason why this wouldn't work? Would I have to call `.ToList()` before mapping the objects to ensure I don't run into the same problem while mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework recursively include collection for each entity from included collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945115/entity-framework-recursively-include-collection-for-each-entity-from-included-co)

Comment: I can understand not wanting to expose `IQueryable`, but I don't see the logic in not exposing `IEnumerable`.  For a start, both your alternatives implement it.

Comment: Also, your example doesn't compile (collection has no name, your selector doesn't specify any properties). It looks like your requirement could be met my just returning `dbContext.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).Where(x => x.Name.Contains("test"))`, so it perhaps doesn't really illustrate your point.

Comment: Why not just wrap the `IEnumerable` so that it can't be cast back to a queryable type? `.AsEnumerable().Skip(0)` for example, though one could easily provide a single-call method to do the same.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer, it is not a duplicate. I know how to include children. The question is about how to do a single trip to the database WITHOUT making the return type something that can modify the query.

Comment: @CharlesMager, implementing IEnumerable and setting it as the return type are two different things. EF only hits the database once you starting iterating over the collection. If you allow IEnumerable to be the return type, a developer could alter the query outside the service before the collection is iterated.

Comment: @adam0101 that's not true. And query tacked on to the `IEnumerable` will be done in memory. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet).

Comment: @CharlesMager, no I can take an `IEnumerable<T>`, cast it back to IQueryable using `AsQueryable()`, add additional criteria, call `.ToList()` and I can see the criteria in the SQL using SQL Profiler. Perhaps that link only pertains to Linq-To-Sql, not EF?

Comment: Actually, after testing it, it does apply to EF too, but only if a developer doesn't cast it back to an IQueryable.

Comment: @JonHanna, that's an option, but it's easier to enforce if you require a fully executed collection as the return type. That way you don't have to know the implementation details and could even write a custom check-in policy.

Comment: Why would have have to know the implementation details?

Comment: @JonHanna, how else would a code reviewer be able to determine if the IEnumerable represents a collection that cannot be cast back into IQueryable? If you use a type that definitely can't, then you remove all doubt.

Comment: Then call the wrapper `TypeThatDefinitelyCantBeCastBackToIQuery<T>`. Better than wasting time and memory memory on collections you don't need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a navigation property in your `Parent` entity like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
   //..
}
```

Then I suggest you create two new classes in your service layer (could be `ParentViewModel`, and `ChildViewModel`) to save the result of your query. In both classes declare only the properties that you need in your presentation layer. Then map your entities with your ViewModel classes using [Automapper](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/).

After that you can do a query like this:

```
var query =dbContext.Parents
                    .Include(p=>p.Children) // load the related entities as part of the query
                    .Where(p=>p.ParentName.Contains("test"))
                    .ProjectTo<ParentViewModel>();
```

Use [`ProjectTo`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) extension method of Automapper.

As you can see in the [link](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/) I quoted above, Automapper supports Nested Mappings, so if you have in your `ParentViewModel` a property of type `ICollection<ChildViewModel>` and you also mapped `Child` entity with its ViewModel, then Automapper will helpfully automatically attempt to map from one type to the other.

All this is going to happen in one round trip to your Database, because `ProjectTo` is an `IQueryable<TEntity>` extension method and it's translated to a `Select`.

Comment: Please, the person who  downvote, could you explain why to improve my answer?

Comment: Maybe, *maybe* because `ProjectTo` returns an `IQueryable`, which the OP doesn't want. But I think that's nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plain ol' EF and no AutoMapper using an Anon query internally, but still get strongly typed objects returned in the end result:

```
public class Human
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Human> Children { get; set; }
    public Human Parent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

var family = await db.Humans
    .Where(h => h.SomeCriteriaForParent == criteria)
    .Select(h => new {
        H = h,
        HH = h.Children
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.HH.Concat(new[] { x.H }))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

If for example your criteria was Id and your Id was say, 5, you'd get the parent with Id 5 and all of its children, in a single `Human[]` array.

Important note on the `SelectMany`: You may want to use `Select`/`GroupBy` here instead.

If you use `SelectMany`, and your criteria select only one parent: You will get the parent and all of its children in a single array. (This was my use-case.)

If you use `SelectMany`, and your criteria select multiple parents: You will get the parents and all their children in a single array.

If above and parents who are children (grandparents/grandchildren) meet the criteria: You will get the full family tree in a single array and you will likely get dupes if you don't add `.Distinct()`.

If you use `Select`: You will get sets of children separated out by parent, into multiple arrays. This was not my use case, but I suspect if it's yours what you actually want here is a GroupBy.